# Add layout update if block is being rendered

Tags: magento

I've created a widget that can be included on any page.  It requires some css/js to work correctly.

Whenever the block is being used, I want to include a custom layout handle.  Then in my layout xml file I can add my files to the head.

For example, when the block is loaded

```
$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('namespace_module_widget');
```

Then in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/namespace/module.xml`:

```
<layout>
    <namespace_module_widget>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>namespace/module/css/module.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </namespace_module_widget>
</layout>
```

The problem is the timing.  By the time it's my block's turn to be rendered, the `head` has already been rendered.  I've tried adding the layout the block's `_construct()` and in `_afterToHtml()` but neither worked.

I also tried using an observer, where I would look through the blocks using `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getAllBlocks()` for mine.  I tried events `controller_action_layout_load_before` and `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` but was unsuccessful.

How can I include my css/js in the `head` conditionally, depending on if my block exists in the request?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, you can't add a handle after your block has been generated, because the updates are loaded first, even before the layout XML and blocks are generated. However, you can get the head block in the _prepareLayout method of your widget block. In your widget block class, override the _prepareLayout method from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract. Then get the head block and add what you need to it:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Widget extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{        
    protected function _prepareLayout() {

        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $head = $layout->getBlock('head');
        $head->addCss('namespace/module/css/module.css');

        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work either.  I think because the `head` block is already rendered, added files never get included in the head tag.

Comment: By the time `_prepareLayout` is called no blocks are rendered.